# Partition n items into groups such that there is exactly one group of size k

Tags: probability, set-partition

**Question**: Assume we have $n$ items that we seek to partition into $m$ groups. What's the probability that exactly one of the partitions has the size of $k$ (others can have less or more than $k$ items)? 
**More general question**: Assume we have $n$ items that we seek to partition them into $m$ groups. What's the probability that exactly $t$ of the partitions have the size of $k$ (others can have less or more than $k$ items)?
Is there any way to avoid complicated formulas driven by inclusion-exclusion?

Thanks

Comment: 1.  Where did you encounter this problem?  Did you pose it yourself, or is it in a class, or what?  Are you studying a specific topic in probability and combinatorics?  2.  Please spell "wanna" as "want to."

Comment: You have to state the statistical assumptions about choice of groups.

Comment: Are the items identical or distinct?

Comment: It's not for a class (I'm done with classes as a grad student), I'm just testing something in Bioinformatics and want to test an approach mentioned in a published paper (by others) from a probabilistic point of view. Assume you have $n$ strings (uniformly distributed in range $1$ to $A$). After assigning values, let's partition them based on their values. Strings with the same value go into one bucket. What's the probability of getting exactly one bucket of size $k$? Size of other buckets can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the combinatorial class of  sets with size $k$ marked we
find

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}_{\lt k}(\mathcal{Z})
+\mathcal{U} \textsc{SET}_{= k}(\mathcal{Z})
+\textsc{SET}_{\gt k}(\mathcal{Z})$$

and build the generating function

$$\exp(z) + (u-1) \frac{z^k}{k!}.$$

The probability is then given by

$$\frac{1}{A^n} n! [z^n] [u^1]
\left(\exp(z) + (u-1) \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)^A.$$

To get the coefficient on $[u^1]$ we differentiate and set $u=0$,
obtaining

$$\left.\frac{1}{A^{n-1}} n! [z^n] 
\left(\exp(z) + (u-1) \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)^{A-1}
\frac{z^k}{k!}\right|_{u=0}
\\ = \frac{1}{A^{n-1}} n! [z^n] 
\left(\exp(z) - \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)^{A-1}
\frac{z^k}{k!}.$$

Extracting coefficients from this we find

$$\frac{1}{A^{n-1}} \frac{n!}{k!} [z^{n-k}] 
\left(\exp(z) - \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)^{A-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{A^{n-1}} \frac{n!}{k!} [z^{n-k}] 
\sum_{q=0}^{A-1} {A-1\choose q} 
(-1)^q \frac{z^{qk}}{k!^q} \exp((A-1-q)z)
\\ = \frac{1}{A^{n-1}} \frac{n!}{k!} [z^{n-k}] 
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor - 1} {A-1\choose q} 
(-1)^q \frac{z^{qk}}{k!^q} \exp((A-1-q)z)
\\ = \frac{1}{A^{n-1}} \frac{n!}{k!} 
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor - 1} {A-1\choose q} 
(-1)^q \frac{1}{k!^q} [z^{n-(q+1)k}] \exp((A-1-q)z).$$

We thus get for our probability

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{n!}{A^{n-1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/k\rfloor - 1} {A-1\choose q} 
(-1)^q \frac{1}{k!^{q+1}} 
\frac{(A-1-q)^{n-(q+1)k}}{(n-(q+1)k)!}.}$$

We can verify this formula by enumeration, which is
shown below.

```
with(combinat);

ENUMX :=
proc(A, n, k)
    option remember;
    local res, part, psize, mset;

    res := 0;

    part := firstpart(n);

    while type(part, `list`) do
        psize := nops(part);
        mset := convert(part, `multiset`);

        if [k, 1] in mset then
            res := res + binomial(A, psize) * 
            n!/mul(p!, p in part) *
            psize!/mul(p[2]!, p in mset);
        fi;

        part := nextpart(part);
    od;

    res/A^n;
end;


X := (A, n, k) -> 
n!/A^(n-1) *
add(binomial(A-1,q)*(-1)^q/k!^(q+1) *
    (A-1-q)^(n-(q+1)*k)/(n-(q+1)*k)!,
    q=0..floor(n/k)-1);
```

Comment: Your $A$ is the OP's $m$, right?

Comment: What language is this code in?

Comment: I answered the question as clarified in the comment. Variables are from the most recent comment. Language is Maple.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Marko. I tried to come up with a closed form and I failed. I guess this would be the best form. I wanted to first take $log$ of the answer and then take derivative and set it to zero. Thanks again.